# Comments not Purple coloured when using /// in Xcode (swift)

Tags: comments, swift2, xcode7

this may not be very important, but during a few Xcode 7 betas I found that Apple introduced a new way to add comments to methods in Swift using three forward slashes above the method ( /// ), when you add this and use your variable/method somewhere else, Xcode will use your comment to show extra info about the method, type.

This kind of comment used to be purple for a few Xcode 7 beta builds, but it is shown green to me now (similar to the rest of normal commenting ( // or /* */ )

Is there any setting in Xcode that should have changed for this to happen, do you know If I can change anything to bring the Purple colour back to these kind of comments?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The color of the documentation markups can be found in the Xcode preferences (tab "Fonts & Colors", line "Documentation Markup").

Comment: I wonder why Apple added the default setting as Purple first and then changed it back to green. Maybe they didn't like it at the end... This solution works anyway, thanks!